# find minimum number with 2d array c

Tags: c, arrays, minimum

i want to find the smallest number in every one row.. but whats wrong in here...

```
#define NUM_EXAM    3
#define NUM_STUDENT 5
```

find minimum function :

```
int find_min(int score[NUM_EXAM][NUM_STUDENT]) {
    int exam;
    int least;
    int k, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= NUM_EXAM; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= NUM_STUDENT; j++)
            least = j;
```

function :

```
for (k = j + 1; k < NUM_STUDENT; k++)
            {
                if (score[j] < score[k])
                {
                    k = j;
                }
                exam = score[j];
                score[j] = least;
                score[least] = exam;
            }
    printf("%d", exam);
}
```

main function :

```
int main(void) {
    int score[NUM_EXAM][NUM_STUDENT] = { { 60, 80 ,43, 78, 93 } ,{ 75,59,81,77,81 } ,{ 83,74,97,73,81 } };
    find_min(score[NUM_EXAM][NUM_STUDENT]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= NUM_EXAM; i++)` -> `for (i = 0; i < NUM_EXAM; i++)` + `for (j = 0; j <= NUM_STUDENT; j++)` -> `for (j = 0; j < NUM_STUDENT; j++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed some minor things:

- Already mentioned, you need to change the loop condition to < instead of <=, otherwise you access an element outside of the array size
- When calling the function, just pass the name of the array, not the size. Check e.g. [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays-functions)
- As I think you have some overhead in your implementation, I tried to reduce it and if I didn't misunderstand the assignment, the following code shall give you the desired solution:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define NUM_EXAM    3
  #define NUM_STUDENT 5

  void find_min(int score[NUM_EXAM][NUM_STUDENT]) {
      int exam;
      int least;
      int i, j;

      for (i = 0; i < NUM_EXAM; i++)
      {
          least = 0; 
          for (j = least; j < NUM_STUDENT; j++)
          {
              if (score[i][j] < score[i][least])
              {
                  least = j;
              } 
           }

           printf("%d\n", score[i][least]);
      }
  }

  int main(void) {
      int score[NUM_EXAM][NUM_STUDENT] = { { 60, 80 ,43, 78, 93 } ,{ 75,59,81,77,81 } ,{ 83,74,97,73,81 } };
      find_min(score);

      return 0;
  }
  ```